# Feedback for Camelot

Tags: python, user-interface, sqlalchemy, cross-platform, python-elixir

My needs :

1. I need to develop an GUI application that is cross platform
2. the chosen solution must be the fastest to implement
3. it should be easy to extend

The application is just a database front-end, mainly for CRUD operations, listing, filtering, exporting, charts and graphs etc.

After reading about some solutions (Python Card, PyGUI, DABO, pygtkhelpers, kiwi, pyjamas, pure-mvc, PyQt/PySide, Wax, Tk-based frameworks, AVC, Fox etc.), I found myself interrested in two particular solutions, one of them is Camelot.

Before jumping into it, I would like to have some opinions about Camelot users vs skeptics.

Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I saw that this has been voted for closure. Since no one left a comment, I thought it would be good to tell you why this is so. Mostly questions asked on stackoverflow is about objective questions involving code etc. I understand that there are exceptions littered all over stackoverflow. How ever it will be good if you asked the same question on Programmers - Stack exchange.

Comment: I understand, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am a Camelot committer.

If the question has been raised on the Programmers Stack Exchange, please link to it.
This question is kind of old, but for any reference, i'll chime in.

Camelot was and is developed for exactly the reasons you stated. It has matured a lot since this questions was asked and is about feature complete. Latest efforts have been made to use Declarative instead of Elixir. Stability and speed are strongpoints as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best option for this would be to make a CGI program to run through a browser so that you do not have to worry about platform issues. Granted it might take a little bit more work, it may be better suited for cross platform deployment. :)